# filepicker.io : is there a way for passing on access token for facebook photo upload

Tags: filepicker.io

Currently i am using filepicker.io for uploading photos from facebook as well as desktop. Our application login requires facebook-auth.

My specific question is : Is there any way were user does not need to do f-connect again while trying to upload facebook photos. Because as such user has already done the f-connect to login  to website.

Any help/alternatives would be great.

Answer (score 0):

We don't support this due to privacy concerns with the user. Besides technical headaches, sharing an authorization key between apps is not in good faith with the user or Facebook developer TOS

Comment: It would be really nice if Filepicker iOS supported the Account Framework for smoother Facebook login rather than popping up a second login via Facebook SDK as mentioned in this post. Double login is super annoying. Social Framework would a single tap solution to address this UI problem and satisfy privacy concerns.